# checking for some extension and it's not working

Tags: python

So i have the following problem, this is not working:

```
if any(x in pageName for x in ('.jpg','.gif','.txt','pdf','.msi','print'
                                   '.ppt','.pptx','javascript:',
                                       '.xls','#','.xlsx','.doc', 'ftp'
                                '.docx','mailto:','.xml','.tar.gz','.png'
                                )):  
            print pageName
            return []
```

And this is working, so what is the problem in my code, any ideas:

```
if any(x in pageName for x in ('print')):  
        print pageName
        return []
```

Comment: `('print')` is `'print'` just like `(1+1)` is `1+1`. Tuples with single element have to be written with comma: `('print',)`.

Comment: Works fine for me. Note that you forgot to put a comma between `'print'` and `'.ppt'` and `'ftp'` and `'.docx'`. Python will interpret these two as `'print.ppt'` and `'ftp.docx'`.

Comment: yeah you are right i have missed some commas.

Answer (score 3):

```
any(x in pageName for x in ('print'))
```

returns `True` if any of the letters `p`, `r`,  `i`, `n` and `t` occur in `pagename`. Is this really what you want?

To check for `"print"` you'd simply need

```
if "print" in pagename:
```

If you do want to make this extendable, use

```
if any(x in pageName for x in ('print',)):
```

(notice the comma? That creates a tuple. Otherwise, the parentheses would simply be ignored.)